# Frames Configuration of Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

In emacs `C-x r f` remembers the frames configuration to a register. How I can 'see' it ?  `M-x view-register` doesn't show it.  I also like to store different configurations and re-call them as  I need them  across emacs sessions.

Comment: I am looking for something like: M-x save-frame-configuration RET my-project-view-1.   and then  M-x load-frame-configuration RET my-project-view-1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> is bound to `jump-to-register`, and you can find the code you need in there. You can use either <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-function` or <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-function-on-key` to conveniently jump to the source.

The function obtains an argument `register` and then calls `(get-register register)` to obtain the data. The following code then deals with restoring the frame or window configuration as required.

The "c" code to `interactive` means a character, so the `register` argument is just a character. You could therefore use `(get-register ?a)` to obtain register `a`.

```
(defun jump-to-register (register &optional delete)
  (interactive "cJump to register: \nP")
  (let ((val (get-register register)))
    (cond
     ;; [...]
     ((and (consp val) (frame-configuration-p (car val)))
      (set-frame-configuration (car val) (not delete))
      (goto-char (cadr val)))
     ((and (consp val) (window-configuration-p (car val)))
      (set-window-configuration (car val))
      (goto-char (cadr val)))
     ;; [...]
     )))
```

Comment: Registers are not persistent across Emacs sessions, so this does not really respond to the request.

Comment: The question was: How does one obtain a window configuration from a register? I believe aartist then intends to use that information to implement persistence across sessions, but there was no request for help with doing that.

Comment: Suit yourself, but aartist had already replied to choroba, before your post, that (a) he knew how to restore a frame config from a register during the same session, and that (b) he was looking for how to do that across sessions. That was why I left the comment.

Answer (score 1):

The `winsav.el` library is alive, but the new version is on Launchpad as part of nXhtml. The easiest way to get winsav and set it up is just to download the whole of nXhtml and install it. (If you want it to load fast then just byte compile the whole nXhtml - FROM the nXhtml menu.)

If you for some reason believe it is better to just have `winsav.el` then it is in the util subdirectory:

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~nxhtml/nxhtml/main/files/head:/util/

(Note that the zip files for downloading nXhtml are a bit old now. In fact everything in my Emacs pages are a bit old at the moment. Except for some parts of nXhtml that I update now and then. And the sources for EmacsW32 - which are not up to date but include man.

Comment: Winsav does a good job. What I am looking for though is storing different configuration  to different register and making that persistent across session. Something like M-x call-frame-configuration my-project-view1

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the documentation:

> Use <kbd>C-x r j R</kbd> to restore a window or frame configuration.  This is
>   the same command used to restore a cursor position.  When you restore
>   a frame configuration, any existing frames not included in the
>   configuration become invisible.  If you wish to delete these frames
>   instead, use <kbd>C-u C-x r j R</kbd>.

(Where R stands for the register.)

Comment: I am looking for the configuration in names/numbers. I know how to restore them within session.  I like to save them across emacs sessions.

Comment: Ah, I see. `desktop-save`, then?

Answer (score 0):

With [*Bookmark+*](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/BookmarkPlus) you can [*bookmark*](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/BookmarkPlus#DesktopBookmarks) an Emacs desktop.  Unfortunately, a desktop does not record the frame configuration.  (You can also bookmark a frame configuration, but that is only for the same Emacs session, since they are not peristent.)

I believe there are, however, some libraries that let you save a window or frame configuration persistently (and then restore it).  You might try Lennart Borgman's [`winsav.el`](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/DL/elisp/winsav.el&sa=U&ei=gMPvTs33G9KBsgK9h9W5CQ&ved=0CA8QFjAA&usg=AFQjCNEJbIkkSZAbpFD74HMtDzNKk3qLfw), for instance.  I know that a couple of years ago he was working on that feature -- dunno what the status is now.  If it works, then you can also bookmark persistent frame configs.